# MySql SUBSTRING_INDEX how not use sequence scan

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table structure MySql v 5.7.11 :

```sql
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
`gender` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

and this table have more than 100 million records
I need to get mail domain from email field and count by each domain, for example such as: google.com, yahoo.com, etc..

I use query:

```sql
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(`users`.`email`, '@', -1) col1,
  count(1)
FROM `users`
GROUP BY 1
```

But this query it takes a long time more than 2 minutes. I can't change structure this table. How not use sequence scan, and how I can accelerate this query?

Comment: What MySQL version do you use?

Comment: It is not the scan that is causing the performance problem, it is the filesort on the `group by`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot speed this query up without changing your data structure. The most straightforward solution would be to add a [generated column](http://mysqlserverteam.com/generated-columns-in-mysql-5-7-5/) that calculates the domain on the fly store it, and your query would run on this field.

If you absolutely cannot a field to this table, you may still be able to add another table to the database that would hold the id of the users table and the domain name. You add an after update and an after insert trigger to the users table that calculate the email domain names for each new or updated user records. You also initially have to fill up the new table. Your query will run a lot quicker on the new table.

Comment: Worth mentioning: Generated columns can be indexed (virtual columns only from MySQL 7.7).

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a straightforward way to speed up this query without modifying the table, given it can't make use of an index.

However, consider what is your use case. i.e. is the functionality important enough for your application to track these statistics separately? For example, if you had `users_email_stats` table including columns `domain` and `total`, you could then

- pre-load the data from your above query into it
- update totals every time user email is touched (either with the database trigger or from your application)

The advantage of this table would be that it would:

- be relatively compact compared to your main users table
- be completely disposable, as the data can be reconstructed easily from `users`
- contain exactly the data you need and querying it would be very fast

The obvious cost would be the additional maintenance of updating counters.